# for loop in va_list procedure, continue used aimlessly(?) K&R

Tags: c, pointers, for-loop, continue, kernighan-and-ritchie

Good afternoon! I have some doubts about following code.

[1] What does the middle condition in the for loop mean? ; `*p;` and `; *sval;`  - reaching an end of input string? If yes, how is it determined?

[2] I do not understand that complicated for loop.

Let's suppose that if condition is not satisfied `*p == %` so we go into switch right away. Now let's consider opposite case, we enter every other char despite `%`, if is satisfied so we use continue and also go to `switch` after that. What's the difference between those 2 cases then ?
I must be terribly wrong with sth, but I can't find my mistake for over 2 hours now...

```
#include <stdarg.h>
/* minprintf: minimal printf with variable argument list */
void minprintf(char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list ap; /* points to each unnamed arg in turn */
    char *p, *sval;
    int ival;
    double dval;

    va_start(ap, fmt); /* make ap point to 1st unnamed arg */

    for (p = fmt; *p; p++) {         /* [1] */
        if (*p != '%') {
            putchar(*p);
            continue;                /* [2] */
        }
        switch (*++p) {
        case 'd':
            ival = va_arg(ap, int);
            printf("%d", ival);
            break;
        case 'f':
            dval = va_arg(ap, double);
            printf("%f", dval);
            break;
        case 's':
            for (sval = va_arg(ap, char *); *sval; sval++)
                putchar(*sval);
            break;
        default:
            putchar(*p);
            break;
        }
    }
    va_end(ap); /* clean up when done */
}
```

Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we `continue`, we just print the character, and skip the switch altogether. The loop goes through the format line looking for (1) a terminating zero, or (2) a percent sign.

When the terminating zero is reached, the loop ends:

```
for (p = fmt; *p; p++)
//            ^^^ Here is the condition: *p != 0 is implied
```

When a percent sign is reached, the following symbol is taken as a format character, and the next vararg is interpreted according to it.

---

There is a bug in this program - it produces a read past the end of the format string (an undefined behavior) when the percent symbol is the last character of the format string. Try this:

```
minprintf("%\0bug!bug!bug!");
```

The simulated end-of-line marker `\0` is skipped, and the `bug!bug!bug!` output is produced. The reason for this is an unconditional pre_increment of `p` in the header of the `switch` statement. To fix this problem, add the following case to the `switch`:

```
 case '\0':
    p--; // reverse the ++p from the header of the switch
    break;
```

Comment: Thanks. I have a question about that bug. Why is \0 skipped, which line does it? And as for me that accidental %\0 and behavior you described is not an error. It just omits that \0 and prints words after it. If %\0 would be at the end of a string then no printf would occur, and it would end correctly. Am I right?

Comment: @PeterKowalski When you pass a string ending in `%`, e.g. `"Hello %"`, `miniprintf` would read past the end of the string, which is prohibited. I put a terminating zero in the middle of my string literal to illustrate the point that a read beyond null termination will happen. It does not matter that the program may not always crash: an undefined behavior could lead to unintended consequences, and must always be avoided.

Comment: OK. Now I understand. However, shouldn't it be --p instead of post-decrement ?

Comment: @PeterKowalski Take a look at [this link](http://ideone.com/f3rzJ) to see another example when an unwanted garbage is printed after a string that ends in `%`.

Comment: @PeterKowalski Pre-increment or post-increment does not matter in situations when the value of the increment/assign expression is not used; you can use either one.

Answer (score 1):

*p  *sval - dereference pointer which points on the char in the string.
In C strings are terminated by "\0" symbol.
So if value that we get from place where p, sval point is zero we obviously has reached the end of the string

2 in loop continue is used to skip all statement following it and return to the loop header with executing (;;statement)

Answer (score 1):

- [1] is to continue loop until it doesn't get null terminating character `'\0'` of string.
- [2] is to print character if its not `'%'`. If its `'%'` next character in the string identifies how to print the next `va_arg` from the list.